# how to apply custom validation on different controls in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, validation

I am using DropdownBox and TextBox in my c# application.

I need to validate that either DropdownBox item should be selected or TextBox should have the value

But not both have value.

How can I apply validation on both together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (with a `CustomValidator` control):

```
protected void cvName_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
  if (myDDL.SelectedItem == null && myTB.Text == "") //If nothing is selected in the drop down AND the text box is blank...
  {
    args.IsValid = false; // Set the validator to false
  }
}
```

The conditions on the `if` statement will depend on your validation requirements, but this gives a general idea of what to do.  Hope it helps!

See this [this post](http://www.tutorialsroom.com/tutorials/details/asp-net-validation-controls-part3) for some good details about validation.

**NOTE**: You don't need to assign a `ControlToValidate` to a `CustomValidator`.  Just set the above function as the `ServerValidate` event for the `CustomValidator` and it will fire when the page submits.